# Placing nova tools in resource sidebar

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a nova sidebar with resources and tools. The resources are in a group called 'System'. The bottom 2 are the tools. How do I adjust the position of Analytics(tool) to be below Activities(resource). By default tools are placed below resources.

[image]

```
public function tools()
{
    return [
        new Matches(),
        new Analytics(),
    ];
}

protected function resources()
{
    Nova::resources(
        [
            Activity::class,
            AdminPermission::class,
            Lead::class,
            Plan::class,
        ]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommend to use [Collapsible Resource Manager](https://novapackages.com/packages/digital-creative/collapsible-resource-manager). It is complete lifesaver for larger Nova applications. With this package you can order menus in any way, add extra links and much more.

But if you don't want to install extra package, you can try

1. Hide **Analytics(tool)** from sidebar with [custom navigation](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/tools.html#navigation) and just pass empty view.
2. Add empty **Analytics(resource)** and try to redirect it your **Analytics(tool)**